JWT Authentication with Symfony 6.4
I am trying to create an authentication form with Symfony using JWT. I installed the Security bundle, created the User entity, and then installed LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. Afterwards, I configured everything as shown in the documentation. I used Postman to test, and everything worked fine; I obtain the token. However, I'm currently stuck at this step, unsure of what to do next. Could you please provide guidance on the subsequent steps?
I installed the Security bundle, created the User entity, and then installed LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. Afterwards, I configured everything as shown in the documentation of symfony . I used Postman to test, and everything worked fine; I obtain the token. However, I'm currently stuck at this step, unsure of what to do next. Could you please provide guidance on the subsequent steps?"

Take that JWT token and put into Postman authentication Bearer token field.

When you got the token, In Postman you should add the header:
Authorization: Bearer ${token} to every request
